# How to call a function from the interactive interpreter and pass arguments for argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, command, line, argparse

I have a Python function `myFunc` defined in a file `test.py`. I want to test this function from the Python interpreter in interactive mode and pass it command line parameters for argparse to parse. From the Python interpreter I enter `from test import myFunc`. I want to then be able to run 'myFunc' in interactive mode... but pass it several command line arguments.

For instance I have tried `myFunc() arg1 arg2` however the Python interpreter reports a SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

If I simply type `myFunc()` the function does run but there are of course no arguments passed.

I realize that I could include the following in my code...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myFunc()
```

I could then run from the command line 'python test.py arg1 arg2' and
this does work.

However I would like to know if it is possible to test the `myFunc()` function from the Python interpreter in interactive mode and pass it command line parameters for argparse to parse.

```
import argparse
from textwrap import dedent
import sys

def myFunc():
    print "hello!"
    print str(sys.argv)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Prog',
                                     formatter_class= argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
                                     description = dedent('Program to control Tycon TDDin2 Relay states'))
    parser.add_argument('addr',
                        help='ip[:port] address of target device. ' \
                        'Port defaults to the snmp port of 161.')
    parser.add_argument('relay',type=str, help='name of relay')
    parser.add_argument('action', type=str, help='action = Open, Close or Cycle')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print('args = ' + args.addr + ' ' + args.relay + ' ' + args.action)
```

Answer (score 2):

`parse_args` takes a list of strings to parse; the default value of this argument is `sys.argv[1:]` (well, really `None`, which will be interpreted as a request to use `sys.argv[1:]`). Add the same argument to `myFunc`, to be passed directly to `parse_args`.

```
def myFunc(cli_args=None):
    ...

    args = parser.parse_args(cli_args)
    print('args = ' + args.addr + ' ' + args.relay + ' ' + args.action)
```

Now you can call `myFunc` with whatever list of arguments you want:

```
myFunc(["192.0.2.24", "foo", "Open"])
```

Keep in mind that `parse_args` effectively exits the interpreter if the list of args can't be successfully parsed (rather than just raising a custom exception), so you'll want to be prepared to catch the `SystemExit` exception.

Comment: Thank you... that does work. I previously didn't have the correct syntax for the call... myFunc(["192.0.2.24", "foo", "Open"])

Comment: That is a very good point you make regarding the importance of catching the SystemExit exception.

Comment: You could probably just monkey-patch or mock `ArgumentParser.error` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying `myFunc` you can modify `sys.argv` in interactive mode, it will be parsed when function is called:

```
sanyash@sanyash-ub16:~/myrepos/trash$ python2.7
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import file
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv = ['./file.py', 'some addr', 'some relay', 'some action']
>>> file.myFunc()
hello!
['./file.py', 'some addr', 'some relay', 'some action']
args = some addr some relay some action
>>>
```

Comment: Mutating global state is generally frowned upon during tests.

Comment: @chepner, the unittest file for `argparse` does test the parser by modifying `sys.argv`.  That gets as close to the real world commandline use as testing can get.  It also tests via `parse_args(alist)`.  Sanyash is demonstrating an interactive test, not a fromal unittest.

Comment: Given that `error` calls `sys.exit` in the first place instead of simply raising an exception, I wouldn't consider `argparse` a paragon of good practice.

Comment: @chepner if you are really interested in advocating for a better solution, perhaps you should offer one

Answer (score 0):

In an iteractive `ipython` console session, I can copy-n-paste your function (with a few changes) and easily test it.

```
def myFunc(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Prog',
       formatter_class= argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
       description = 'Program to control Tycon TDDin2 Relay states')
    parser.add_argument('addr',
                        help='ip[:port] address of target device. ' \
                        'Port defaults to the snmp port of 161.')
    parser.add_argument('relay',type=str, help='name of relay')
    parser.add_argument('action', type=str, help='action = Open, Close or Cycle')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return args
```

test empty command line:

```
In [7]: myFunc([])                                                              
usage: Prog [-h] addr relay action
Prog: error: the following arguments are required: addr, relay, action
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3299: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

`ipython` captures the exit.

`myFunc()` would look at `sys.argv`; producing the same error message because my session commandline has nothing to do with this parser.

test help:

```
In [8]: myFunc(['-h'])                                                          
usage: Prog [-h] addr relay action

Program to control Tycon TDDin2 Relay states

positional arguments:
  addr        ip[:port] address of target device. Port defaults to the snmp port of 161.
  relay       name of relay
  action      action = Open, Close or Cycle

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 0
....
```

test with a valid list:

```
In [9]: myFunc(['testpy','arg1','arg2'])                                        
Out[9]: Namespace(action='arg2', addr='testpy', relay='arg1')
```

This displays the `args` namespace returned by the function.